# Did Eleven ever try to see this character?

Tags: stranger-things

In Season 4 of *Stranger Things*, we see that

> Hopper is alive.

We also see that Eleven left the door to her cabin open, because as she states, she never stopped believing that he could still be around.

However, we also know that with a photograph or something of the sort, or perhaps simply with a strong connection in some cases, Eleven is capable of remotely perceiving people, apparently regardless of distance. This would seem like the natural thing to do if she never believed that he was really gone.

So did Eleven ever try to perceive Hopper? If so, did she succeed, or did it fail for some reason?

Comment: Vecna has shown him fighting, otherwise we don't know, but earlier they thought he was dead, so why look for him? Not checking on Mike is a bit more surprising, but after she checked on Hawkins, she went out to go there instead of looking any further.

Comment: @Mithoron - It seems that you may have downvoted, but you should consider before doing so that Eleven explicitly said that she never stopped thinking he must be alive, and she had at least a few days to check up on him between her fight with Vecna and his return. And bear in mind, one of the first things she did after recovering her powers was to check on her friends.

Comment: Well, there's a better reason possible, that she was afraid to find out. All this feels kinda like speculation, though. Besides, it's not like there's no big plot hole in there - where did Russians get the monsters?

Answer (score 5):

> However, we also know that with a photograph or something of the sort, or perhaps simply with a strong connection in some cases, Eleven is capable of remotely perceiving people, apparently regardless of distance.

If Eleven had tried at any time between Hopper's "death" and the end of episode 7/beginning of episode 8 of season four, it would have failed because she didn't have her powers.

When she does finally recover her powers, she has more immediately pressing things to deal with: she needs to find a way to save her friends in Hawkins, Papa tries to force her to stay (including drugging and collaring her), Sullivan and his men attack, and then she still needs to save Max from Vecna.

It's possible that in the few days between her "mind fight" with Vecna and Hopper returning to Hawkins that she may have tried to see him. If she did it wasn't shown on screen, but now that she has her powers again it would presumably have succeeded.